# Subtracting date to get the difference in years

Tags: sql, oracle, date

Hello evreryone I was trying to subtract two date to get the difference in years.

```
select round(date '99-11-05' - date '69-05-21')/365 from dual;
```

this is working fine as I am getting output 30.47945205479452054794520547945205479452.

I have a table RAP07 where I am having two date fields BIRTHDT_T and SPRODT_T, if I subtract both so I should get the age of person in years.

I tried below query:

```
select round(date BIRTHDT_T - date SPRODT_T)/365 from rap07;
```

But i got the error 'ORA-00936: missing expression'
Could you please help me out on this.

Comment: What's `BIRTHDT_T` amd `SPRODT_T` data type and data value?

Comment: @D-Shih data type is date and value is in format of 02-JUL-44.

Comment: It is useless to run `DATE` or `TO_DATE(...)` on a column which is already a `DATE`, just use `BIRTHDT_T` and `SPRODT_T`. And a DATE value in Oracle does not itself have any format! What you see is a (default) **output** format.

Comment: `DATE '99-11-05'` gives `0099-11-05`, i.e. 99AD - I don't think that is what you like to get. Looks like when the [Y2K-Bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2000_problem) was present all over the developers from today were still young kids at this time.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=44b3c03c8abd6cfb0c34a3bec39896d8)**

```
select floor(months_between(date SPRODT_T, date BIRTHDT_T) /12) from rap07;
```

OUTPUT:

```
YR
32
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first select, you only get one result, which comes back fine. In your second query, you try to get a column with results, which gives an error, as you didn't name the column. Also, you use the keyword date in both queries. This keyword is only used on making a new date, not on resolving a date. Try if this query works:

```
SELECT ROUND(BIRTHDT_T - SPRODT_T)/365 AS years FROM rap07;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you cannot use "date" before an **already defined column from a table**. That is the reason you are getting that error.

**Option 1**

In Oracle there is a function that can extract the year from a column of date datatype ( `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM COLUMN)` )

```
select round(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM BIRTHDT_T) - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SPRODT_T)) from rap07;
```

So you don't actually need to divide and round anything.

**Option 2**

If you still want to use the expression that you've mention (without EXTRACT), you can do it like this:

```
select round(BIRTHDT_T - SPRODT_T)/365 from rap07;
```

Comment: `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ...` returns wrong result, e.g. for `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE '2018-02-01') - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE '2016-12-01') => 2`

Answer (score 0):

You should better use

```
TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SPRODT_T, BIRTHDT_T)/12)
```

`FLOOR(...)` instead of `TRUNC(...)` does the same.

Otherwise you may get wrong results, e.g. for this:

```
ROUND(DATE '2018-02-28' - DATE '2010-03-01')/365 -> 8.0027397260274
```